# How to detect and replace non-printable characters from table?

Tags: mysql, non-ascii-characters, system-stored-procedures

I have imported data from xls file into table. but there are some garbage (non ascii charactors).

I want to remove those non printable characters from database.

here is the query i found which can  select the entries which has non-ascii characters

```
 select * from TABLE where COLUMN regexp '[^ -~]';
```

But how can i remove those characters from table using mysql query or procedure ?

Please give suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (e.g. [kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji)) is not the same as [non-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (e.g. [ESC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) and [BEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)).  Which are you seeking to remove?

Comment: It seems you cannot. Look at this [possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql). You may also want to refer to [MySQL documentation on REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: actually when i am view table i see square bracket in column. when i copy that square bracket and paste in notepad it show [sub] in black background block. how to remove that ?

Comment: Check that you are using the right encoding in notepad. Also check that you are using the right encoding when transferring from xls to database.

Comment: What was the character was in that position in the original XLS file?

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about "detect and replace" I wouldn't suggest the Delete query from @TheWitness. Instead I would do something like this:

```sql
UPDATE some_table SET some_column = REGEXP_REPLACE(some_column, '[^ -~]', '') WHERE some_column  REGEXP '[^ -~]'
```

The query above will use regular expression to search for the particular characters and with REGEXP_REPLACE it will replace them with empty string.

More on [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Answer (score -1):

It's fairly simple, you just change your SELECT into a DELETE as follows

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN regexp '[^ -~]';
```