# First letter change to uppercase with MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278207/mysql-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-existing-table) shows me how to create a function and then UPDATE a table making a column first letter uppercase which is pretty involved?  I simply want to output results where FirstName and LastName capitalize the first letter.  Right now they are a mixture of all uppercase, lowercase or correctly formatted.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, r.Email, min(ListingID) as ListingID, ListingFirmID
    FROM sancap_Residential_Property e 
    JOIN sancap_Agent r ON e.ListingAgentID = r.AgentID
    JOIN sancap_Office d ON e.ListingFirmID = d.firmID
    WHERE ListingFirmID != 'BrokerC'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingFirmID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT concat(UPPER(SUBSTRING(trim(FirstName),1,1)),lower(SUBSTRING(trim(FirstName),2))) as FirstName, concat(upper(substring(trim(LastName),1,1)),lower(substring(trim(LastName),2))) as LastName, r.Email, min(ListingID) as ListingID, ListingFirmID
    FROM sancap_Residential_Property e 
    JOIN sancap_Agent r ON e.ListingAgentID = r.AgentID
    JOIN sancap_Office d ON e.ListingFirmID = d.firmID
    WHERE ListingFirmID != 'BrokerC'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingFirmID
```

Comment: Strange...the altered query totally ignores the case issue and produces the same result as the original query?

Comment: That's not possible. try this SELECT concat(UPPER(SUBSTRING('rocco',1,1)),SUBSTRING('rocco',2)) as FirstName

Comment: That worked!  Why does the data from the table not work?

Comment: It should work. please load your sample data and table to sqlfiddle so I can check

Comment: Is there a hidden/blank character before the first character in the names?

Comment: Oh yes that's possible, just trim your data and remove non printable character if any

Comment: I have updated answer that trim data before making upper case

Comment: Same result with the trim.  The current data is a mess of uppercase, lowercase and mixed case...would that matter?

Comment: No that doesn't matter. It looks like there must be hidden non printable character in starting

Comment: So I think you want only first character as upper case and other in lower. I have updated answer . just remove non printable character and try above query

Comment: check this link to remove nonprintable character:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535350/remove-all-or-particular-non-printable-character-from-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(FirstName,1)), RIGHT(FirstName,LENGTH(FirstName) - 1)), CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(LastName,1)), RIGHT(LastName,LENGTH(LastName) - 1)), r.Email, min(ListingID) as ListingID, ListingFirmID
    FROM sancap_Residential_Property e 
    JOIN sancap_Agent r ON e.ListingAgentID = r.AgentID
    JOIN sancap_Office d ON e.ListingFirmID = d.firmID
    WHERE ListingFirmID != 'BrokerC'
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, r.Email, ListingFirmID
```

Comment: Getting this error?  [Err] 1305 - FUNCTION databasel.LEN does not exist

Comment: Actually I like Ronak Shah solution better.

Comment: That executes, but both you and Ronak solutions display the data in the same format as the original query.